# Sencha CMD build classic app not working but modern does

Tags: extjs, sencha-cmd, extjs6-classic

I have sencha Universal app. Recently i switched from windows to Linux so i have to reinstall everything. 
Now my `sencha CMD` version is `v6.7.0.63`, app version is 6.2.167. When i try to create new app with CMD it is successfully creating the new app, and `sencha app build classic` on this newly created app is also good. But when i try to build the old app, it is not working. My Old app build ios is also working. But not the classic.

Here is the error it gives when i run `sencha app build classic`

> ## Exception information:
>
> Sencha/Cmd/6.7.0.63/plugin.xml:333: The following
>   error occurred while executing this line:
>   htdocs/pi-v3/public/App/.sencha/app/build-impl.xml:273:
>   The following error occurred while executing this line:
>   htdocs/pi-v3/public/App/.sencha/app/js-impl.xml:186:
>   com.sencha.exceptions.BasicException
>        at com.sencha.ant.AntScript.execute(AntScript.java:121)

and when i run `sencha app build ios` it run without any error

Comment: So are you using all these tools similar like windows like cmd version/sencha version ?

Comment: what do you mean? what tools? if you mean sencha cmd, yes i am. what else would i use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was so unclear in linux. But i was able to solve it. As you can see the error doesn't say anything about the head or memory but it was actually error due to small heap size. so i have to increase the memory using;

```
export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xms1024m -Xmx2048m"
```